# Explicit prefetching of non-contiguous data

Tags: c++, caching

I do a lot of operations on sub-regions of images. For example, If I have a 100x100 image, I might want to iterate over this image and process blocks of 10x10 pixels. For example:

```
for(each 10x10 block)
{
  for(each pixel in the block)
  {
    do something
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that the small blocks are not contiguous chunks of memory (i.e. the image pixels are stored in row major order, so when I access the 10x10 block, the pixels in each row of the block are contiguous, but the rows of the block are not contiguous. Is there anything that can be done to speed up the access to the pixels in these blocks? Or is it just impossible to get fast access to a region of a data structure like this?

From a lot of reading I did, it sounded like something like first reading the pixels as the only operation in a loop might be useful:

```
// First read the pixels
vector<float> vals(numPixels);
for(pixels in first row)
{
val[i] = pixels[i];
}

// Then do the operations on the pixels
for(elements of vals)
{
 doSomething(vals[i])
}
```

versus what I'm doing which is both simultaneously just:

```
// Read and operate on the pixels
for(pixels in first row)
{
 doSomething(pixels[i])
}
```

but I was unable to find any actual code examples (versus theoretical explanation) of how to do this. Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Copying the pixels into a vector will place them into a contiguous memory region, which, if they fit into a cache line, will typically be cached.

Comment: @chradcliffe but will that help anything if they are only used once?

Comment: I think @MvG has the right answer to this one. `__builtin_prefetch` would be the right thing to use. I had forgotten about that builtin. It will save the copy and work in the case that you're only using the value once.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` has a builtin functioncalled [`__builtin_prefetch`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fprefetch-3264). You can pass an address to that function, and on targets that support it, `gcc` will emit a machine instruction causing that address to be loaded into cache even though it isn't used immediately.

Many modern image-processing applications store images in *tiles*, as opposed to the *rows* (a.k.a. *scanlines) you describe. E.g. GIMP [does that](http://developer.gimp.org/writing-a-plug-in/3/index.html). So if you have control over the way the image is stored, then using a tiled approach will likely increase locality and therefore reduce cache misses and improve performance.

Comment: Using the scanline storage system, do I have to prefetch every address of the small image blocks? Or just the addresses of the first pixel in every row of the row block?

Comment: @DavidDoria, whenever you prefetch one byte of data, its whole cache line will be loaded into cache. How that relates to your image depends on CPU architecture, memory alignment and so on. In general I'd assume that preloading the first pixel for every row *should* be enough. If in doubt, try both approaches and benchmark them.